# Считывание формулы откуда-либо и распознавание

Tags: c++builder, алгоритм, embarcadero, c++

Есть таблица. В ячейке таблицы записана формула типа =A1+B1*C1/5, где А1 - первый ряд первый столбик, В1 и С1 соответственно. Нужно разпознать записанную (допустим, в Edit1) формулу и выполнить описанные в ней действия между описанными в ней ячейками и цифрами. Все операции эквивалентны.

Какие алгоритмы распознавания можете предложить?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то switch в С++ позволяет только 1024 case'ов, потому таблица будет не больше 1024 / 26 ячеек. Такое наверное даже на курсовую не пойдет, не то что на программу, за которую заплатят деньги.
Сделать базовый класс operand, от него два наследника cell_2d и const_value. Cell_2d инициализировать строчкой адреса строки ("A1", "B2"...), const_value - константой из формулы. Добавить метод GetValue, для const_value он будет возвращать константу, для cell_2d - значение ячейки, адресом которой инициализирован экземпляр класса. Стек сделать в виде указателей на operand.

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста подробно как метод GetValue  будет возвращать   для cell_2d значение ячейки, ато я новичок в ооп.

Comment: Ну, у Вас значение ячейки в общем случае = строковая переменная. Не думаю, что есть смысл ваять тип вроде TVariant. Вот берете и возвращаете объект типа строка. Прототип получается примерно такой:

    std::string GetValue(void);

Comment: А как вот Cell_2d инициализировать строчкой адреса строки ("A1", "B2"...)?

Comment: GetValue возвращает не адрес ячейки, а то, что по этому адресу лежит. 
Например:
operand* op = new Cell_2d("A1");
op -> GetValue(); вернет число, которое лежит в ячейке "A1".
Соответственно стек наполняется указателями на такие объекты во время разбора, в во время вычисления значения для каждого элемента стека вызывается GetValue.
Если так нужно, то в классе operand можно завести строку для хранения адреса ячейки. А вообще я бы хранил адрес в структуре {x,y}, и просто бы преобразовывал его для пользователя в вид "A1, B2".

Comment: Извините за тупые вопросы, но я не очень понял как Cell_2d инициализировать А1, А2, А3 и тд...

Comment: Создаете конструктор, который принимает строковое значение.

    class Cell_2d
    {
       public:
         Cell_2d(std::string x); // конструктор с параметром.
       private:
         Cell_2d(); // конструктор по умолчанию. Мы его вызывать не будем.
    };

Comment: Как GetValue() будет определять координату ячейки, дабы определить ее значение?  Это нужно прописывать соответствие, допустим А1=Cell(1,1)? И как это будет выглядеть( напишите пожалуйста пример кода).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все просто. Алгоритм таков

1) Ячейка пуста? Если да - на выход.

2) Первый символ ячейки '='? Если нет - у нас там данные, иначе - формула.

3) Если у нас в ячейке формула, то мы начинаем анализ строки. В формуле ничего кроме трех видов сущностей быть не может:

- операторы ('+', '-', '/', '*');
- координаты ячеек вида <символ><число> (напр., C1);
- числа (целые);

Вызовы ф-ций (COS(), SIN(), SUM() и пр.) пока опустим.

Распознать координаты и числа можно банально натравив токенизатор, указав в качестве разделителя массив возможных операторов. Это если делать совсем халявно. Если же делать чуть более усложненно - нужно делать автомат. Т.е. условно идем по строке от начала к концу и анализируем каждый следующий символ.

Когда мы уже получили окончательный вариант хранения формулы в памяти (ну, например, действительно организовали стек), то идем по нему и подставляем вместо каждой координаты ячейки ее текущее значение.

Касательно перевода координат ячейки вида C1 в координаты таблицы. Это сделать очень просто. Мы можем представить левый верхний элемент как (0;0). Он же соответствует A1. Когда мы идем по строкам - у нас увеличивается значение столбца. Получается ряд A2, A3.... Если перевести в координаты, то это, очевидно, будет (0;1), (0;2) и т.д. Если идем по столбцам - аналогично. Итого: если координаты хранятся в двух переменных `char x` ('A') и `int y` (уже переведенное в число значение), а нам нужно адресовать ячейку в массива mas, то получается такое выражение: `mas[x - 'A'][y - 1];` При этом нужно быть внимательным с допустимыми значениями.

NB! Легко возможна ситуация зацикливания. Например, C1 = B1, B1 = C1. Вариантов два.

Первый: инициализировать изначально все ячейки нулями. И строго регламентировать порядок, по которому идет подсчет ячеек. Итак, получится, что первая ячейка получит значение 0, т.к. вторая ячейка будет подсчитана позже и пока что в ней 0. А вторая получит 0, т.к. завязана на значение первой ячейки, а там УЖЕ 0.

Второй вариант: просто не допускать зацикливание на этапе ввода значения ячейку. Подчеркну - скорее не в самом процессе ввода, а по факту его окончания (пользователь перешел в другую ячейку, нажал Enter и т.п.)

**P.S.** Во избежание изобретение велосипеда с потерей большого объема крови, предлагаю посмотреть исходные коды таких продуктов как OpenOffice (или LibreOffice) или Gnumeric (электронные таблицы GNOME)

Answer (score 4):

Очень хороший пример калькулятора с рекурсивно-нисходящим парсером нашелся здесь: http://forum.algolist.ru/3432-post5.html

Все что остается — поменять в `next()` чтение с `getchar()`/`ungetc()` на работу с буфером, или где оно там лежит, да расширить принимаемую грамматику, добавив «переменные». Ну и проглотить начальное "=", разумеется.

Если выражения могут быть особо большими и сложными (т.е. простенькому рекурсивному парсеру могут сорвать стек), и нет скобок — грамматика получается регулярной, можно парсить тривиальным конечным автоматом. Если нет — взять какой-нибудь парсерогенератор, типа ANTLR или Flex+Bison, и пусть сам пишет код. Вот, скажем, пример простого калькулятора с применением Flex и Bison: http://www.progtools.org/compilers/tutorials/cxx_and_bison/cxx_and_bison.html

Answer (score 3):

[Обратная польская нотация (запись)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C).

> Стековой машиной называется алгоритм, проводящий вычисления по обратной польской записи. [Пример](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80_.D0.B2.D1.8B.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.B2.D1.8B.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B9).

Comment: C польской нотацией я разобрался, но дело в том, что  у меня в формуле есть не только числа, а и переменные А1, В1 и тд... Сложновато распознавать эти переменные, в отличиит от чисел, которые можно сразу StrToInt и считать. Сдесь нужно использовать сase...